# SailsJS: How to define a custom type attribute for a Model without creating a new relationship

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I have a model `Budget` and I need to store an array of `Budget_Item` on it. If I declare as a new model type it will be stored in a new table and become a new relationship which I think it's not the best practice. In this context I think I need a kind of hybrid with relational and non-relational database for this `Budget_Item`.

The only approach with my knowledge is to solve it by defining `Budget_Item` array as a `json` type and casting it afterwards before using.

The best way to explain my case is to  give an approach of what I want if I were in Matrix where everything is easy and possible, and would be the following:

model `Budget.js` :

```
module.exports = {

  primaryKey: 'id',

  attributes: {

    id: {
      type: 'number',
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },

    .  .  .

    budget_items: {
      type: 'BudgetItem[]'     <===========What i need======
    },
}
```

Did someone been on a similar situation or knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there an item and budget table?

Comment: Yes, i have a table Budget, but i don't want a BudgetItem relationship table given they're not going to repeat anymore, so I just want to set it as an attribute of Budget

Comment: You could try something like `type:'json', column_type:'blob'`.

Comment: Was thinking about this more, you could always just stringify the data before saving.

Comment: I think best way for this is `type: 'string' , columnType: 'text'` and stringify before create.

Comment: I've solved setting budget_items as ```type: 'json'```. So why do you think is better setting as string and columnType as text? Just to know...

Comment: Ok, your solution is better, after i read documentation. It's the same thing in db but when u use json, sails automatically stringify and parse json.

Comment: good to know I were in the right way and confirmed by official documentation without knowing it :P. Thanks!!